# Problema al llenar array php con datos de BD

Tags: php, html, sql-server, array

Intento llenar un array con datos extraidos de una bade **SQLServer** pero mi problema es que guarda solo el ultimo registro.

```
<?php 

    if(isset ($_POST['buscar'])){
        $con = conectar_sql();
        $caja = $_POST['cod-caja']; 
        $result = sqlsrv_query($con,"SELECT      Tipo, NroInt, CodBode, Folio, Fecha, Usuario, Total
                                    FROM         softland.iw_gsaen
                                    WHERE     (Folio < 0) AND (CodCaja = '$caja') AND (Tipo = 'b')");
        if(sqlsrv_has_rows($result)){
            ?>
            <div class="alert alert-info"> <strong>Caja: <?php echo "$caja"; ?></strong></div>
            <div align="center">
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col"> <div align="left">
                                <button type="submit" href="lib/borrar_documento.php?B=<?php echo codificar($dhatos);?> " class="btn btn-danger " id="borraro_todo"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Borrar todo</button>
                            </div></th>
                            <th scope="col">Folio</th>
                            <th scope="col">Bodega</th>
                            <th scope="col">Fecha</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody> 
                        <?php                                   
                        while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)){
                            $datos = array("NrpInt" => $row[1],"FOLIO" => $row[3],"CAJA" => $caja);
                            $datos_todo = array($caja);
                            $datos_todo[]=$row[1];
                            ?>
                            <tr>  
                                <th scope="row"><div align="center"><a title="Eliminar" onClick="return confirmacion();"  href="lib/borrar_documento.php?B=<?php echo codificar($datos);?> " class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a></div></th>
                                <td><div align="center"><?php echo $row[3]; ?></div></td>
                                <td><div align="center"><?php echo $row[2]; ?></div></td>
                                <td><div align="center"><?php echo formato_fecha($row[4]); ?></div></td>

                            </tr>

                            <?php
                        }
                        print_r($datos_todo);
                        ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <?php
            }
        ?>
```

Este es el resultado que obtengo,en la parte superior.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Que tal, Podrías agregar a tu pregunta el resultado del Query? para ver cual es el resultado que esperas

Comment: Agregue mas código a la publicación

Comment: Esta rato comoe estas armando el array, pero por cada ciclo del while estas seteando la variable $datos_todos =  array($caja) por lo que vas a obtener solo el ultimo que pasó por ahi..

Comment: Que datos quieres obtener en el array ?.

Comment: el codigo de caja y los NrpInt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema que tienes en el código es que estás reiniciando el valor de `$datos_todo` por cada registro obtenido de la base de datos con la asignación `$datos_todo = array($caja)`, perdiendo así su contenido anterior.

Te recomiendo usar [`array_push()`](http://php.net/array_push) para incorporar de manera explícita el valor como un nuevo elemento de la matriz en vez de usar `$datos_todo[] = ...` y así evitarte confusiones:

```
/* Damos un valor inicial a la variable */
$datos_todo = array();
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)) {
  $datos = array(
    "NrpInt" => $row[1],
    "FOLIO" => $row[3],
    "CAJA" => $caja,
  );
  /* Cargamos este dato en $datos_todo */
  array_push($datos_todo, $datos);
  /* ... */
}
/* Ahora te saldrá bien */
print_r($datos_todo);
```

En la documentación te recomiendan no usar `array_push()` para agregar un único valor porque te evitas la sobrecarga de una llamada a función, pero su uso podría ayudarte a evitar confundir una asignación de valor con añadir un nuevo índice y la diferencia de rendimiento es inapreciable (sobre todo con pocos registros).

Comment: Anteriormente ya había probando con algo como esto  ** array_push($datos_todo, $datos);**  pero obtuve el mismo resultado

Comment: ¿Has probado lo que te he puesto? El principal problema era la asignación anterior, no el uso de `[]` o `array_push()` para agregar un nuevo elemento.

Comment: si me retorno esto _Array ( [0] => Array ( [NrpInt] => 80654539 [FOLIO] => -80654539 [CAJA] => E05 ) )_  pero sigue retornando el ultimo dato

Comment: ¿Usaste mi código y eliminaste la asignación? Recuerda que es MUY importante eliminar la asignación a la que hago referencia en mi respuesta. Comparte cómo ha quedado tu código editando tu pregunta si sigues teniendo problemas.

Comment: saque la declaración del array fuera del ciclo y funciono

Answer (score 0):

**Encontré la solución**

```
$datos_todo = array($caja); //saque la declaración del array fuera del ciclo 
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)){

$datos = array(
"NrpInt" => $row[1],
"FOLIO" => $row[3],
"CAJA" => $caja
);
```

/* Cargamos este dato en $datos_todo */
$datos_todo[] = $datos['NrpInt']; //decidí no utilizar array_push para evitar sobrecarga